# How to set the cluster for my NetBeans Modules Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, configuration, netbeans-platform

This seems to be a simple thing, but I can't figure out why some of the modules I created end up in different clusters (i.e. ide) and others on the cluster by my branding token.

The only module that shows under the branding token has this configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <moduleType>autoload</moduleType>
                <codeNameBase>com.validation.manager.h2/1</codeNameBase>
                <publicPackages>
                    <publicPackage>org.h2.*</publicPackage>
                </publicPackages>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Where the others look like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <moduleType>eager</moduleType>
                <codeNameBase>com.validation.manager.ui/1</codeNameBase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see, besides the module type and having public packages or not, there barely any differences.

The application works fine, is just something that has been puzzling me.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at the effective pom for the respective projects, eg to see how the http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/nbm-mojo.html#cluster property is defined.

Comment: All modules, including the one that seems to work fine, have the cluster configured to the same value: <cluster>validation_manager_client</cluster>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in your module's nbm file what cluster is defined in Info/Info.xml.

- If it has wrong or missing value, you have to look in the module's pom
  configuration why it's so. Either it badly defined in the pom.xml or
  in the deprecated src/main/nbm/module.xml
- The module might end up in "ide" cluster because you defined
  defaultCluster parameter in your application

that's the behaviour for modules in the current nbm-maven-plugin. For osgi bundles the behaviour is more fluid as the bundle jars don't contain cluster information in the binary.

Comment: All modules had the correct defaultCluster in their info.xml files, including the ones that show on the correct cluster and the ones that doesn't. No defaultCluster was defined anywhere else.

Comment: then either file an issue against nbm-maven-plugin with a reproducible case or debug the goal that creates the cluster structure in the application.

Comment: in your app, the files under application/target/${branding_token} seem to be arranged correctly. So it's only a maven output issue? in that it suggests that stuff below "Processing ide cluster" fall under the ide cluster while in reality they don't?

Comment: Might be misleading then :P